# Can't decipher Software Updater error

Tags: update-manager

Trying to do a Software Updater update. Get this error which appears to say it needs the same software that it is trying to install:

**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are 
missing or not installable. 
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not 
allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gnome-software-plugin-snap: 
Depends: gnome-software (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) 
but 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 is to be installed
ubuntu-software: Depends: gnome-software (>= 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) 
but 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 is to be installed
```

Comment: you can just try installing the package specifically. you can just do `sudo apt-get install gnome-software` to install the latest version or if you want to check by yourself then
do `apt policy PACKAGENAME` to check the versions and choose the version latest version ( of course it should be `>=3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0` ) by doing `sudo apt-get install gnome-software=<version you chose>`

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT That fixed it (sudo apt-get install gnome-software). Thanks! You should put that as an answer.

Comment: YO, I posed this as the answer, good to know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above one can easily deduce that doing `sudo apt-get install gnome-software` or `sudo apt-get install gnome-software=<version you chose>` would solve this problem as it would install the missing package that is causing the Software Updater to fail.